# Let $\bigcup $ of $ A_m$ be $\{ (x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\quad s.t \quad y = mx\}$ where $m$ is a real.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I understood the intersection because it's basically the set that all the sets share, which is the origin. Can someone explain why the answer to the union is: "$\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $y$-axis excluded origin." Unless I wrote down the wrong notes this doesn't make sense. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $\bigcup A_m=\Bbb{R^2}-\{(0,y)| y\neq0\}$.

First let $(x,y)\in\bigcup A_m.$ Then $\exists m\in \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $(x,y)\in A_m$. Then $y=mx$, so if $x=0$ then $y=0$, so $(x,y)\notin\{(0,y)|y\neq 0\}$. Thus, $(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}-\{(0,y)| y\neq0\}$, so $\bigcup A_m\subseteq\Bbb{R^2}-\{(0,y)| y\neq0\}$.

Now let us assume that $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R^2}-\{(0,y)| y\neq0\}$. if x=0 then y=0, so $(x,y)=(0,0)\in \bigcup A_m$ if $x\neq 0$ then let m=y/x. Thus y=mx, so $(x,y)\in A_m$ so $(x,y)\in\bigcup A_m$ then $\Bbb{R^2}-\{(0,y)| y\neq0\}\subseteq \bigcup A_m$ .

So, $\bigcup A_m=\Bbb{R^2}-\{(0,y)| y\neq0\}$